# How can I allow multiple memberships for a single contact under one organisation?

Tags: civimember

There are two scenarios 
**First**
a. I create contribution page with membership types A, B, C, D and then user goes to the contribution page and purchases membership type A
b. I again go to the contribution page and this time purchase membership type B
**Result** -->  Membership Type - B
i.e. At first my membership type was A but after purchased membership type B, I have Membership Type B
**Second**
a. I go to contact dashboard , open membership tab and click on + Add Membership --> select membership type A 
b. I again to contact dashboard open membership tab and click on + Add membership --> select membership type B

**Result** --> ** Membership Type A and Membership Type B both
i.e. I have two memberships A and B
I know since all membership type belongs to one organisation , we maybe getting the above issue, is there any chance we can implement scenario second with  contribution pages ?

is there any better solution than as provided in the old post here : 
https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=31251.0.html

Answer (score 1):

The logic behind the behaviour you're observing is that most of the time when a contact is paying for a different membership type than their existing one, they are upgrading or changing that membership. Whereas an administrator is doing it, they can be trusted to differentiate between an update/change vs. a new one.

The link you provided suggests that if you create membership type A and B associated with different organizations, then the system knows not to change a membership, but to create a new one. That seems like a good idea, but it depends on your own details - the membership model in civicrm has trouble capturing all the possible nuances of memberships in real life.

Here's a link to one of my recent projects that provides support for multiple memberships:

https://socius.cpha.ca/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=2

Comment: Great example !!! thanks for a elaborate explanation !!!